# CakePHP has and belongs to many conditions with NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

```
$conditions = Array
(
  [table] => products_pages
  [alias] => ProductsPage
  [type] => inner
  [foreignKey] => 
  [conditions] => Array
  (
   [0] => ProductsPage.product_id = Product.id
  )
)
```

I'm trying to set up NOT EXISTS conditions, like the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM products_pages,products 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                  from products_pages 
                  where products_pages.product_id = products.id)
```

So basically select any product that doesn't exist in the products_pages table.

What is the proper way to format that SQL statement for CakePHP and replace it here:

[conditions] => Array
   (
   [0] => (What's the proper way to insert above SQL here?
   )

Would really appreciate your help guys, I've been trying to figure this out for about 5 hours with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always use `query` if you don't find the way to do it with CakePHP:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

In this case security wouldn't be compromised as you are not using any input.

Anyway, something simple would be just to do it in more than one step:

```
//selecting the products in the productcs_pages table
$productsWithPages = /* query to get them*/

//getting an array of IDs
$productsWidthPagesIds = Hash::extract($productsWithPages, '{n}.Product.id');

//doing the NOT IN to select products without pages
$productsWithoutPages= $this->Product->find('all', 
        array('conditions' => 
             array( 'NOT' => array('Product.id' => $productsWidthPagesIds )
        )
);
```

Comment: It would be nice if you accept the answer as valid :) (that tick on the left of my answer)